# Why can't I use yield with return?

Tags: python, function, return, python-2.x, yield

I would like you to consider the following code:

```
def func(alist):
    if len(alist) == 1:
        return arg * 2
    for item in alist:
        yield item * 2
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator
```

Now, I realize that I cannot do this.  However, I would like to know why.  What exactly is going on behind the scenes that is causing Python to throw the `SyntaxError`?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would want to sometimes yield and sometimes return. How would you use such a function properly? Wouldn't you need to inspect the length of the list you pass it beforehand, to make sure you call it the right way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the Python interpreter implicitly create the generator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825357/why-doesnt-the-python-interpreter-implicitly-create-the-generator)

Comment: Rather than what you're trying, it would almost certainly be a better idea to always `yield` the results.

Comment: no yields do not have defined length and can be infinite; there is no way to know which one you want based on usual python paradigms

Comment: @Kevin - Because the list can be either 1 item exactly or many, many items.  If it is only one, then using `return` is simple and good.  Otherwise, I wanted to make a generator in order to return the items one at a time (thus cutting down on CPU usage).  However, the main point of my question is "Why can't this be done?"

Comment: "_If it is only one, then using return is simple and good_". Can you explain how it would be simpler and better than using `yield`?

Comment: Because I originally didn't really see a reason to create a generator for only 1 item.  However, I've kinda come to the conclusion that that is what I should do.  Like I said before though, the main point of my question was "Why can't I?" not "Should I?".  I am curious as to how Python works internally and why it won't let it.

Comment: Since Python 3.3 you can.  See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python has to decide whether a function is a generator at bytecode compilation time. This is because the semantics of generators say that none of the code in a generator function runs before the first `next` call; the generator function returns a generator iterator that, when `next` is called, runs the generator code. Thus, Python can't decide whether a function should be a generator or not by running it until it hits a `yield` or a `return`; instead, the presence of a `yield` in a function signals that the function is a generator.

Comment: I accept your answer because you answered what I wanted: "Why can't this be done?".  The other answers focused more on finding a way around it (which is nice, but not what I wanted exactly).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See here: [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained)

This describes your issue in detail.
In short, because the way Python will interprate the function (either as an generating object or a returning object, everything in Python is objects and some things will define that object as a specific type. In this case Yield is a generating object)

TL;DR: You can't use `yield` and `return` within the same function. Use either one as many times as you wan't within the function, just not both.

Answer (score 0):

Is not that, you cannot use a return with yield, but rather, you cannot use return with argument, when your function has a yield making it a generator

You might want to change your implementation to

```
def func(lis):
    for item in lis:
        yield item * 2
```

Comment: May as well just delete the `if` entirely and do `def func(lis): for item in lis: yield item * 2`

Answer (score -1):

What you want is indeed possible:

```
def func(lis):
    if len(lis) == 1:
        return lis[0] * 2
    else:
        return (item * 2 for item in lis)
```

This returns a value in the one case and a generator in the other case.

But be aware that this will lead to problems: On every call, you will have to make the distinction

```
res = func(lis)
if len(lis) == 1:
    print res # my value
else:
    for i in res: print i # several values
```

It is much more advisable to make the two use cases distinct:

1. You can do

   ```
   def func(val):
       return val * 2
   ```

   and, when you need, do either of

   ```
   reslist = [func(i) for i in lis]
   resgen = (func(i) for i in lis)
   ```

   or
2. you can do

   ```
   def func(lis):
       for item in lis:
           yield lis[0] * 2

   def func1(val):
       for i in func([val]):
           return i # returns the first value
   ```

Answer (score -1):

The other answers already explained the yield/return issue. You can just use `map` to make this much simpler:

```
def func(lis):
    return map(lambda item: item * 2, lis)
   # similar to: return [item * 2 for item in lis]
```

Of course, this will always return a list, because `lis` is a list, even if it only has one item. You can change it to a compound statement:

```
def func(lis):
    return map(lambda item: item * 2, lis) if len(lis) > 1 else lis[0] * 2
```